# Passive Voice of "Do you know her": What preposition should be used?

Tags: passive-voice

When we put the following sentence into the passive voice, is the agent introduced by the preposition *by*, as it usually is with other verbs?

> - Active: Do you know her?
> - Passive : Is she known *by* you?

Comment: Shouldn't it be *"known **to** you?"*. This would then be an exception to the usual rules for putting things into the passive.

Comment: @peter yes sir you are right it should be 'known to....'.    Active: I know him.   passive: he is known to me.

Comment: _Known to_ and _known by_ are different. _By_ is the usual passive; _known to_ is a predicate adjective _known_ plus the governed preposition _to_. They amount to the same thing, but _known to_ is a legal formulation, like _let it be known to all_.

Comment: I'd say yes. To me, "know to" only implies "have heard of".

Answer (score 1):

Active: "Do you know her?"

Passive : "Is she known to you?"

"by you" is used for more active verbs, for example:

"Did you paint that picture?"

"Was that picture painted by you?"

Knowing or not knowing is not an action but a state (in this case of a relationship).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach/thought :

**He is known by me.**
Suggest a more normal two-way relationship.
But it would sound awkward and unnatural to a native speaker.

**He is known to me.**
Suggests a two-way personal relationship.
It sounds like I know him in the sense that I know President Obama.

Comment: By _two-way personal_, do you mean asymmetric? Obama is known to you, but I doubt that you're known to him.